# traversing json object structure contains arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So i have the following structure.. How can iterate over "values" structure to extract all the possible "paramX" arrays... can i use a loop?

Im getting this structure from a call to external service from a javascript call.. So in java script.

```
{

  "booleanValue": true,

  "values": {

    "param1": ["1.00", "20.00"],

    "param2": [ "2,000.00", "200.00"],

    "param3": [  [  "Test1",  "CC1", ], [  "T222222",  "CC2212", ]    ]

  }

}
```

Comment: Most programming languages (including JavaScript) have a JSON parser that will automatically generate an array for you out of JSON.  Then you would loop through your array and extract the values you are looking for.  This question is technically off topic, since you have displayed no effort to tell us what language you are using, and/or the things you've tried.  Your question needs more focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return an array of keys in values and then do a forEach loop on that array:

```js
var str = `{
  "booleanValue": true,
  "values": {
    "param1": ["1.00", "20.00"],
    "param2": ["2,000.00", "200.00"],
    "param3": [["Test1",  "CC1"],["T222222","CC2212"]]
  }
}`;

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

Object.keys(obj.values).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, obj.values[key]);
});
```